# Things bought with haram money

Tags: halal-haram, money

Assalamualaikum,
I hope you and your family are doing well. I wanted to speak to you about a scenario that I have been going through. I took a maintenance loan which is a loan given to University students. I know this loan is haram but I still took it, may Allah forgive me. I have repented and I am still repenting. My question is the items that I bought with this money are they haram for me to use? For example, let's say if I bought a laptop would It be haram for me to start an online business with that laptop and earn through it? Would it be haram for me to use that laptop for general purposes. I have also made the intention that Inshallah when I do earn enough money I will ty to InshAllah give the same amount I received from this loan to Islamic causes for example charity or to someone who is poor without the intention of getting any good deed out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your benefiting from using a laptop or buying it, there is no sin on you, because the sin in borrowing with interest is related to the borrower’s obligation and not to the money, and if that is decided, then there is nothing wrong with anyone benefiting or buying from someone else what he had bought from a usurious loan.

Source here: https://fatwa.najah.edu/question/ref-297331/

Translation in English [here - Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://fatwa.najah.edu/question/ref-297331/).